# How to centre div in another div?

Tags: html, css, center

**div1** is in the centre of screen and I want **div2** in the centre of **div1**

```
<div id="div1">
       <div id="div2"></div> 
    </div>
```

css:

```
 #div1{ 
     top:0;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     bottom:0;
     margin:auto;
     position:fixed;
     width:595px;
     height:842px;
     background-color:#F0F0F0;
 }

#div2{

}
```

Comment: Consier he is New To group and Dont try to Give More Minus Point

Comment: Use margin:0 auto >> exp > https://jsfiddle.net/06uzt7xx/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#div1{ 
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 margin:auto;
 position:fixed;
 width:595px;
 height:842px;
 display:table;
 }

#div2{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
margin:auto; 
background-color:red;
position:relative;
}

</style>
<div id="div1">
   <div id="div2">content</div> 
</div>
```

js fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/GlynneT/06uzt7xx/